# Apache James with AWS Keyspaces for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, james, amazon-keyspaces, apache-james

[image]

Trying to connect Apache James with AWS Keyspaces. James is able to connect but, failing with the above error after few seconds.

[image]

According to the stack trace the exception is thrown from the above method.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

As error message shows, the `now` function isn't supported by Amazon Keyspaces, so James won't work out of box without modification.  You can try to change that function to something like this (see doc for [QueryBuilder](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.10/manual/statements/built/)):

```java
return session.prepare(select()
         .all()
         .from("local"))
         .bind();
```

and rebuild. But most probably, it will fail in some other place.

P.S. Really, there are [plenty of differences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/functional-differences.html) from OSS Cassandra, so a lot of code may not work.

Comment: Yes. I tried the same. got another error.

===============
13:22:11.850 [cluster7-nio-worker-3] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.ERROR - [cluster7] [15.222.43.132/15.222.43.132:9142] Query error after 1 ms: SELECT count(*) FROM keyspaces WHERE keyspace_name=?;
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: countRows is not yet supported.
 at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:181)
 at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:651)

Comment: So Apache James does not support AWS Keyspaces out of the box ?.

Comment: I doubt that it will work without heavy tuning

Comment: Could anyone translate this to cql query.
select()
         .fcall("NOW")
         .from("local"))
         .bind();

Comment: It’s select now() from local;

Comment: You can execute this in keyspaces by executing the following  "SELECT CAST(now() AS timeuuid) FROM local"